# Что должен вернуть статический метод?

Tags: php, ооп

Подскажите пожалуйста, что должен вернуть статический метод `st()`, чтобы на экран вывелось число 8? Вот код

```
interface Counter{
    public static function st($num);
    public function count();
    public function getCount();
}

class FluentCounter implements Counter{
    private $count = 0;
    public static function st($num){
        $count = $num;
        return new FluentCounter;
    }
    public function count(){
        $this->count += 3;
        return $this;
    }
    public function getCount(){
        return $this->count;
    }
}

$num = FluentCounter::st(5)->count()->getCount();
echo $num;
```

Answer (score 0):

Уже сам понял как это сделать)

```
interface Counter{
    public static function st($num);
    public function count();
    public function getCount();
}

class FluentCounter implements Counter{
    private $count = 0;

    public static function st($num){
        $obj = new self;
        $obj->count = $num;
        return $obj;
    }
    public function count(){
        $this->count += 3;
        return $this;
    }
    public function getCount(){
        return $this->count;
    }
}

$num = FluentCounter::st(5)->count()->getCount();
echo $num;
```